# mod_rewrite - redirecting to different protocol, domain & changed query strings

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm redirecting a http www. URL to a new non-www. domain at https, but one particular URL pattern has changed in structure, so I'd like to use a ReWrite Rule for it in htaccess.

Old:

```
http://www.example.com/travel.php?cat=cat1&id=1&title=title-string
http://www.example.com/travel/cat1/1/title-string
```

New:

```
https://newdomain.com/travel/cat1-title-string
```

So for the redirect, the "id" parameter disappears completely, but I'd like the "cat" parameter and hyphen to prefix the "title" parameter in the new URL.

I think this is possible, but I can't figure out how? If it isn't, I'll settle for a rule without the cat parameter:

```
https://newdomain.com/travel/title-string
```

I would like to use an or expression to match the "cat":
(cat1|cat2|cat3)

Comment: You have two URLs listed as your "Old" input. Which one of them should be converted to the new format? Both of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first kind of URL you do this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=([^&]*)&id=[^&]*&title=(.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^travel\.php$ https://newdomain.com/travel/%1-%2? [R=301,L]
```

For the second URL you do this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/travel\/([^\/]*)\/[^\/]*\/(.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/travel/%1-%2 [R=301,L]
```

If `cat1` is should only be work for some spezial values we have to redefine this:

For the first kind of URL you do this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=(cat1|cat2|cat3)&id=[^&]*&title=(.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^travel\.php$ https://newdomain.com/travel/%1-%2? [R=301,L]
```

For the second URL you do this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/travel\/(cat1|cat2|cat3)\/[^\/]*\/(.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/travel/%1-%2 [R=301,L]
```

Replace **cat1|cat2|cat3** with your values